# create gallery image using gridView and intent

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, imageview

I am creating a gallery image android application where  the user can choose any picture from the set of pictures that are existing in the `GridView` and the system will get back the selected item to the first activity and display the image.

The problem is when i click on the button to go to the second activity (ImageGalleryActivity)the gridview do not exist and the set of pictures are not existing can anyone help me to fix this problem ???

MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.harrypottergallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView imgBig, imgBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgBig = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv);
    imgBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_img);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ImageGalleryActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

ImageGalleryActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.harrypottergallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGalleryActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    GridView gridV;

    ImageView imgg;

    // array of small images
    public Integer[] smallImage = new Integer[] { R.drawable.smallpic01,
            R.drawable.smallpic02, R.drawable.smallpic03,
            R.drawable.smallpic04, R.drawable.smallpic05,
            R.drawable.smallpic06, R.drawable.smallpic07,
            R.drawable.smallpic08, R.drawable.smallpic09,
            R.drawable.smallpic10, R.drawable.smallpic11,
            R.drawable.smallpic12, R.drawable.smallpic13,
            R.drawable.smallpic14, R.drawable.smallpic15,
            R.drawable.smallpic16, R.drawable.smallpic17,
            R.drawable.smallpic18, R.drawable.smallpic19,
            R.drawable.smallpic20, R.drawable.smallpic21,
            R.drawable.smallpic22, R.drawable.smallpic23,
            R.drawable.smallpic24, R.drawable.smallpic25,
            R.drawable.smallpic26, R.drawable.smallpic27,
            R.drawable.smallpic28, R.drawable.smallpic29, R.drawable.smallpic30 };

    // array of large images
    Integer[] largImage = new Integer[] { R.drawable.pic01, R.drawable.pic02,
            R.drawable.pic03, R.drawable.pic04, R.drawable.pic05,
            R.drawable.pic06, R.drawable.pic07, R.drawable.pic08,
            R.drawable.pic09, R.drawable.pic10, R.drawable.pic11,
            R.drawable.pic12, R.drawable.pic13, R.drawable.pic14,
            R.drawable.pic15, R.drawable.pic16, R.drawable.pic17,
            R.drawable.pic18, R.drawable.pic19, R.drawable.pic20,
            R.drawable.pic21, R.drawable.pic22, R.drawable.pic23,
            R.drawable.pic24, R.drawable.pic25, R.drawable.pic26,
            R.drawable.pic27, R.drawable.pic28, R.drawable.pic29,
            R.drawable.pic30 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        gridV = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_v);
        gridV.setAdapter(new GalleryIMGAdapter(this));
        gridV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewImage(arg2);

    }

    private void ViewImage(int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv);
        imgg.setImageResource(largImage[arg2]);
    }

}

class GalleryIMGAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mc;

    public GalleryIMGAdapter(Context c) {
        this.mc = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ImageView img;

        if (convertview == null) {
            img = new ImageView(mc);
            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 180));
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

ImageGalleryActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ImageGalleryActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_v"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

log cat

```
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2163)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:494)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-12 13:16:48.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

to

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return smallImage.length;
}
```

Also return

```
return img;
```

in `getView` instead of `null`.

Also add the below in `getView`

```
  img.setImageResource(smallImage[position])
```

Make `GalleryIMGAdapter` an inner class of gallery image activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ImageGalleryActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_v"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you have

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 imgg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv);
```

Also having `setContentView` twice in the same activtiy is a bad design.

Edit:

```
public class ImageGalleryActivity  extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    GridView gridV;
    public Integer[] smallImage = new Integer[] {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridV = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_v);
        gridV.setAdapter(new GalleryIMGAdapter(this));
        gridV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class GalleryIMGAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mc;

        public GalleryIMGAdapter(Context c) {
            this.mc = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return smallImage.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ImageView img;
                img = new ImageView(mc);
                img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 180));
                img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                img.setImageResource(smallImage[position]);

            return img;
        }
    }
}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: the system give me the error when i write  smallImage  error: **smallImage can not be resolved to a variable**

Comment: @user3006788 make your adapter class an inner class of your activtiy. acope of smallImage is within the activity

Comment: @user3006788 check the edit i removed unwanted code. just change the image i used the launcher image. you change only smallImage array. Modify the code accrodingly

Comment: it give  me a force close after i try to run the app see the edit answer

Comment: @user3006788 use my code. `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }` is not changed and see the logcat for exxceptions

Comment: @user3006788 there is no imageview in your xml and you are trying to initialize it. will give you NPE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43044/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user3006788)

Comment: okk sir it show the images thank you  ... i have another question how to get back the selected image to be displayed in the imageView that exist in the MainActivity????